# How can I save PyTorch's DataLoader instance?

Tags: pytorch

I want to save PyTorch's `torch.utils.data.dataloader.DataLoader` instance, so that I can continue training where I left off (keeping shuffle seed, states and everything).

Comment: check here https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-save-dataloader/62813/3

Comment: @Meh Thank you, but torch.save() does not save the state. If I save it and load it again, it will start from the beggining with a new shuffle seed.

Comment: simply using the same shuffle seed should be enough to restart training from the previous epoch. I don't think you can restart in between an epoch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite simple. One should design their own `Sampler` which takes the starting index and shuffles the data by itself:

```
import random
from torch.utils.data.dataloader import Sampler


random.seed(224)  # use a fixed number


class MySampler(Sampler):
    def __init__(self, data, i=0):
        random.shuffle(data)
        self.seq = list(range(len(data)))[i * batch_size:]

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.seq)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.seq)
```

Now save the last index `i` somewhere and the next time instantiate the `DataLoader` using it:

```
train_dataset = MyDataset(train_data)
train_sampler = MySampler(train_dataset, last_i)
train_data_loader = DataLoader(dataset=train_dataset,                                                         
                               batch_size=batch_size, 
                               sampler=train_sampler,
                               shuffle=False)  # don't forget to set DataLoader's shuffle to False
```

It's quite useful when training on Colab.

Comment: I believe you need to sub-select the indices after shuffling. Otherwise you will not know which indices you already covered.

Comment: @fsociety Not in this example. Here I use a constant random seed and I don't shuffle the data every epoch. So, it is enough to only know the last index. However, if one is to shuffle while training (or with no fixed random seed), they should keep all of the covered indices, as suggested by you.

Comment: I don't see a difference. If you want to resume your sampler during an epoch, which is the use case here, you don't know where you left off. So let's say you save ```i``` which is let's say 10. Then you only take all indices larger than that, shuffle it, and pick the next 10. But you don't know which 10 those are. It is quite easy to fix, do the subselection after shuffling with fixed seed.

Comment: @fsociety As illustrated in the code, the shuffling is only done once, which is when the Sampler is instantiated. As the random seed is the same number, we'll get the same order of the indices every time we shuffle the `data` (which is what a fixed random seed mean). In this case, `i` always indicates the same index. So, the shuffling is always done before picking the `i`th element.

Comment: Maybe I am blind, but you are shuffling the data _after_ you pick the index or rather what I mean, after you subsample the indices to consider.

Comment: @fsociety Sorry for that. I wrote this answer a long time ago. I fixed the code. Thanks for mentioning the mistake.

Answer (score 5):

You need a custom implementation of the sampler.
Something hassle-free can be used from: https://gist.github.com/usamec/1b3b4dcbafad2d58faa71a9633eea6a5

You can save and resume like:

```
sampler = ResumableRandomSampler(dataset)
loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=2, sampler=sampler, pin_memory=True)

for x in loader:
    print(x)
    break

sampler2 = ResumableRandomSampler(dataset)
torch.save(sampler.get_state(), "test_samp.pth")
sampler2.set_state(torch.load("test_samp.pth"))
loader2 = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=2, sampler=sampler2, pin_memory=True)

for x in loader2:
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

The native PyTorch support for this is still not available, [but considered for future improvements](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/36650). Still, see other answers for custom builds.